# in R, how to search for a particular pattern in a table of string

Tags: r

```
      V1  V2       V3     V4  V5     V6     V7  V8    V9    V10 V11   V12    V13 V14   V15 V16 V17
1       1  1  round-0  10523 180 yellow     NA  NA           NA  NA           NA  NA        NA  NA
2   11973  1  round-1  19478 150 yellow     NA  NA           NA  NA           NA  NA        NA  NA
3   22428  1  round-2  28928 130 yellow  29928 150 brake  31433 160   red     NA  NA        NA  NA
4   39333  1  round-3  47333 160 yellow  48588 185   red     NA  NA           NA  NA        NA  NA
5   49788  1  round-4  56288 130 yellow  58038 165 brake  59038 175   red     NA  NA        NA  NA
6   64688  1  round-5  71693 140 yellow  74293 192   red  74393 194 crash     NA  NA        NA  NA
7   85148  1  round-6  91648 130 yellow  94648 190   red     NA  NA           NA  NA        NA  NA
8   95598  1  round-7 103653 130 yellow 104903 155 brake 105403 165   red     NA  NA        NA  NA
9  112703  1  round-8 122758 130 yellow 125758 190   red 125758 190 crash     NA  NA        NA  NA
10 136513  1  round-9 146563 130 yellow 147963 158 brake 148063 160   red     NA  NA        NA  NA
11 157118  1 round-10 164618 150 yellow 167118 200   red     NA  NA           NA  NA        NA  NA
12 167568  1 round-11 179123 120 yellow 182023 178   red 182373 185 brake 182623 190 crash  NA  NA
13 193378  1 round-12 200378 140 yellow 201878 170   red 203278 198 crash     NA  NA        NA  NA
```

So I have a table in csv, imported with read.table and looks like the above. As you can see the data is not even in each row. it's in the form of a triplet, with V3 V6 and so on storing string, and they correspond with the number stored in the two cells in front of them

So what has been bothering me is that I can't seem to figure out how to write a count that would count for the number of patterns in the table. My task is to count the number of times crash appear right brake. I know I can use like a nested ifelse thing, like I did for storing the finding out the number that is two cell before brake:

```
df$brake <- ifelse(df$V9 == "brake", df$V7,
                   ifelse(df$V12 == "brake", df$V10,
                          ifelse(df$V15 == "brake", df$V13,
                                 ifelse(df$V18 == "brake", df$V16,
                                        ifelse(df$V21 == "brake", df$V19, 
                                               ifelse(df$V24 == "brake", df$V22, 
                                                      ifelse(df$V27 == "brake", df$V25, NA)))))))
```

, but I have like 35 columns, and I'm just wondering if there's a leaner way to do that. any help will be appreciated :)

EDIT:sorry it was unclear. The main problem I have is how to count how often crash follows brake right after. ( I added the code for extracting the numerical value 2 cells ahead of brake because I was thinking the solution for both would be similar: basically one would be see if 3 cells after any brake is crash, and for another it's to extract the value two cells before brake. sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Please show and explain the expected output that corresponds to the provided input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code showed, I assume that the 'brake' columns are 9, 12, 15, etc.  So, we create a numeric index ('indx') to extract those columns.  A logical matrix is also created for the 'brake' columns ('indx1').  Then, we can create a row index (`1:nrow(df)`), and column index (`max.col(indx1, 'first')`), `cbind` it and extract the elements belonging to columns that are in `7, 10, 13, etc.`.  We change the elements to `NA` corresponding to rows in 'indx1' that are '0' for the `rowSums`

```
indx <- seq(9,ncol(df), by=3)
indx1 <- df[indx]=='brake'
df$brake <- df[indx-2][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(indx1, 'first'))]* 
                    NA^!rowSums(indx1)
 df$brake
 #[1]     NA     NA  29928     NA  58038     NA     NA 104903     NA 147963
 #[11]     NA 182373     NA
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 11973L, 22428L, 39333L, 49788L, 64688L, 
85148L, 95598L, 112703L, 136513L, 157118L, 167568L, 193378L), 
    V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), V3 = c("round-0", "round-1", "round-2", "round-3", "round-4", 
    "round-5", "round-6", "round-7", "round-8", "round-9", "round-10", 
    "round-11", "round-12"), V4 = c(10523L, 19478L, 28928L, 47333L, 
    56288L, 71693L, 91648L, 103653L, 122758L, 146563L, 164618L, 
    179123L, 200378L), V5 = c(180L, 150L, 130L, 160L, 130L, 140L, 
    130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 150L, 120L, 140L), V6 = c("yellow", 
    "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
    "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"
    ), V7 = c(NA, NA, 29928L, 48588L, 58038L, 74293L, 94648L, 
    104903L, 125758L, 147963L, 167118L, 182023L, 201878L), V8 = c(NA, 
    NA, 150L, 185L, 165L, 192L, 190L, 155L, 190L, 158L, 200L, 
    178L, 170L), V9 = c("", "", "brake", "red", "brake", "red", 
    "red", "brake", "red", "brake", "red", "red", "red"), V10 = c(NA, 
    NA, 31433L, NA, 59038L, 74393L, NA, 105403L, 125758L, 148063L, 
    NA, 182373L, 203278L), V11 = c(NA, NA, 160L, NA, 175L, 194L, 
    NA, 165L, 190L, 160L, NA, 185L, 198L), V12 = c("", "", "red", 
    "", "red", "crash", "", "red", "crash", "red", "", "brake", 
    "crash"), V13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 182623L, NA), V14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 190L, NA), V15 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "crash", ""), V16 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", 
"V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
))
```

Comment: I get this error `^(!rowSums(indx1)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator` with this toy set `set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c('brake', 'red', 'crash'), 350, replace=TRUE), 10, 35))`

Comment: @plafort If you look at the data provided by the OP, some columns are numeric and some are non-numeric

Comment: I think OP is looking for the sum of instances where 'crash' immediately precedes 'brake'.

Comment: @plafort `ifelse(df$V9 == "brake", df$V7`, that means the row in V7 that corresponds to V9=='brake' and similarly for the other columns V12, V15, etc, if there is a 'brake' V10 or V13 value is taken.  That is what I understand from his code

Comment: it is the OP's lack of clarity at fault. I think I understand now. They want to look across two columns to check if  'crash' is to the right of 'brake.' So in their example, row 12, column 12 is 'brake', and row 12, column 15 is 'crash'. I guess that that would be the desired identification. But again, they are not clear in their intent.

Comment: @plafort Yes, it is a bit unclear.  I am also assuming that no rows have multiple 'brake'.

Comment: More than two columns! If you look at OPs last code block columns go out to V27!

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I think the OP's original dataset have more columns than the example showed here based on OP's statement `but I have like 35 columns`  But, the code I showed should work with any number of columns if it is spaced as shown in the example

Comment: @akrun  sorry it was unclear. The main problem I have is how to count how often crash follows brake right after. I added the code for extracting the numerical value 2 cells ahead of brake because I was thinking the solution for both would be similar: basically one would be see if 3 cells after any brake is crash, and for another it's to extract the value  two cells before brake. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @KenLam  My code was based on the `ifelse` you showed.  If the expected result is different, you may have to update your post with what you expect in `df$brake` using the example here so that it becomes clear.